# Jubula PostgreSQL Database connection failed

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, database-connection, eclipselink, jubula

I get this error when I try to connect to a Jubula database.

```
2000
Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [org.postgresql.Driver] not found.
```

I guess EclipseLink does not know how to connect. (Using: Eclipse 4.4 for Testers)

Can someone tell me how can I install the Postgre-JDBC driver's jar, in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found it;

You need to install Jubula Database Drivers. Eclipse does not contain it by default.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-jubula-database-drivers

Do it by selecting Install New Software from the menu, then adding Bredex's update site.

```
Name: BREDEX GmbH - Jubula (or whatever)
Location: http://update.bredex.de/jubula
```