# Where Jubula keeps its default tests database?

Tags: database, testing, jubula

I would like to access Jubula's default database from outside the Jubula or, at least, copy it entirely and move to another computer. There is a reason a can not access it from inside and export tests as XML. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's using the [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/) by default. It is stored in your user's libriary. I don't know if it's possible to access it from other applications or another machine, but I recommend you not doing that.

What you want to do, is to set up a "conventional" database - like MySQL or Postgre -, and store your tests there. It has some benefits; users can access it, at the same time; you can easily make backups, etc. Just don't forget to [install the Jubula Database Drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807058/jubula-postgresql-database-connection-failed) like I did.

To save existing tests ("copy it entirely") into this new database, you have to export all Projects to XML. Then disconnect from your H2-database, and select the new database from your connections. Then import the XML file you've just exported, and all your tests will be there. You'll find these commands under the Test menu-section.